# Tick Interval for 5 days

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to have my x-axis displayed for every 5 days in Highcharts but for some reason the dates are being displayed properly.

Here is my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/nk3q5ejL/3/

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["10/08/2015", "10/09/2015", "10/10/2015", "10/11/2015", "10/12/2015", "10/13/2015", "10/14/2015", "10/15/2015", "10/16/2015", "10/17/2015", "10/18/2015", "10/19/2015"],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 5,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can use milliseconds in the `tickInterval` if your chart has datetime axis and this does not seem to be the case (see for example http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats), you're just using an array of strings as categories for your x-axis.

If by *x-axis displayed for every 5 days*, you mean having 10-08-2015, 10-13-2015, 10-18-2015, etc, just use `tickInterval: 5` and that will do the trick.

I modified your fiddle with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/nk3q5ejL/4/

Regards!